# Activate PHP on Apache

Tags: php, apache, configuration, debian

I just bought a virtual server and would like to install owncloud. I navigated to the index.php and I just can download the PHP File. The site is not shown like a normal PHP-Site.

I tried many ways, but I failed every time.
I've added  this lines:

```
Include sites-enabled/
GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: man, thank you. it works. Can you insert your comment to an answer, that i can mark it as answer. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a shell, use `a2enmod` command:

```
a2enmod php5
```